# GREP REGEX for EnCase - Date conversion

Tags: regex-negation

How do I convert February 2, 2002 at 10 to GREP REGEX for EnCase Forensics?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "convert (a date) to regex"?

Comment: Regular Expressions.... like in pearl? It's for EnCase Forensics search on Regular Expression needed to find specific time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know EnCase Forensics and given the astounding number of answers here, I am not alone...
This is probably not even a programming question, more like a superuser one, "how to use a program".
But well, if it uses traditional regexes (regular expressions, right), like in Perl (not pearl), just enter the string as given, it doesn't use any special character used in regexes. Ie. that will be a plain text search.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the format. For Month/Day/Year formatting, I would recommend 0?2/11/(20)?02. This makes a leading zero optional as well as allowing for a 2 digit or 4 digit year.

A general month/day/year date regexp in EnCase could be [01]?#/##/(##)?##. However, there will be many dates in a different format, using abbreviations for months or formatted as year/month/day, etc.

(NB: EnCase uses '#' for [0-9] whereas most grep engines use \d.)

Jon